# check error in javascript included file and work around

Tags: javascript, arrays

For a select box on our website, we have changed the ajax call request to javascript array file which used to fill the city select box options. These are now filled from the same file containing only js array.

This js only array file is created dynamically on some other server and transferred to static server. Most of the times it works good, but fails occasionally and file got corrupted or not fully transferred. In that case the file contents look like

```
var cityArray = [{SID : "15",SN : "Rajasthan",cities : [{CID : "677",CN : "Jaipur"}, //syntax error, no eol
```

So, when we try to use this file, all js stop working.

My question here is how can i check that the included file contains errors and use the legacy method to fill the select box options?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I'd cheat a little:

- Use a `XMLHttpRequest` to fetch a copy of the file as a string instead of adding a `<script>` tag.
- Check if the string has an EOL, if not - add one.
- `Eval()` the string in a try-catch statement.

Not only should that let you use your particular type of 'broken' files, but your script won't fall over if its broken in other ways.

Comment: whats the browser compatibility of XMLHttpRequest?

Comment: @user2319984, Depends how far back you need to go. All 'modern' browsers support it (including mobile devices), IE5/6 you need a small workaround to use but is fine. IE7 and newer are fine. If you happen to be using jQuery then it makes it a tad easier too.